# Computing Hodge numbers of a complete intersection

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, commutative-algebra

The situation is this:

I have a 5-dimensional irreducible projective variety $Y$ embedded in $\mathbb P^{13}$. This variety is singular, the singularities being a disjoint union of two curves. I have been able to compute the dimensions of the **sheaf cohomology groups** $H^i(Y,\Omega_{Y/k}^1)$ for $i=1,2$, with the help of Macaulay2 (these are $1$ and $13$-dimensional respectively), and a few other invariants, such as the normal bundle $h^i(Y,\mathcal N_{Y/\mathbb P^{13}})$.

Let $X$ be the **smooth** variety obtained by intersecting $Y$ with two general hyperplanes $H_1,H_2$ in $\mathbb P^{13}$. Then $X$ is $3$-dimensional, and I can also prove that it is Calabi-Yau. Now computations are not possible by computer anymore, because I no longer have any nice Gröbner basis.

The question is this: What can I  deduce about the Hodge numbers $h^{1q}=h^q(X,\Omega_{X/\mathbb C}^1)$ of $X$ given my knowledge about $H^i(Y, \Omega^1_{Y/\mathbb C})$ (and possibly other properties of $Y$?)? Is there some Lefschetz type theorems with weaker hypotheses (the usual hypothesis of Lefschetz is smoothness of $Y$), for example?

Comment: I feel like the people in commutative algebra are more open to the use of computers, so it didn't strike me as so odd. What someone should really do is clean up the stuff placed in [tag:algebraic-geometry]...

Comment: weakerik weaker https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815204/flatness-of-structure-sheaves